# Is there a way to provide multiple JS scripts within a single <script> tag?

Tags: javascript, css, merge, client

I am building an app in JQM that has multiple instances but the same core of scripts.

Summarizing, every instance will have its own index.html initializing that particular instance with files both taken from the central repository (the common scripts/interface) and from the particular instance (files specific to that instance only).

Since I am adding more capabilities to the application, I need to constantly update the core of scripts with new addons (both 3rd party or custom scripts), but I don't want to go and update all the single instances with the new scripts I'm adding.

My question is: is there a method to include a `<script>` tag inside the index.html of every instance (say `<script src="commonurl/commonscripts.js"></script>`) and on my common repository, in the `commonscript.js` use structures like the java import, to import all the scripts I'm using?
I know it's not how js works, but the core of the question is: do you have any suggestion on how to keep the client unvaried and work just on the server side modifying just the included file, or anyway not having to manually modify the client index.html? Is js minification/merging my only option?

Same question applies to CSS files included in the client index.html.

Hope this makes sense, thanks for the answers!

Comment: have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-to-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to take a look to that too... but I guess Tom's answer below could be the one. I'll try the approaches and report how these go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with requirejs

> RequireJS is a JavaScript file and module loader. It is optimized for
>   in-browser use, but it can be used in other JavaScript environments,
>   like Rhino and Node. Using a modular script loader like RequireJS will
>   improve the speed and quality of your code.

http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out and report here!

Comment: I've ended up using requireJS for its flexibility... I can also load CSS files with it, which is exactly what I needed.